# Meaning of "so that"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is there any answer that clarifies what the "so that" in this context means, and how generally such a sentence serves any context?

> Firstly, the Employer will make a demand on the bank which provided the PB. For tactical reasons, this demand is often made ***so that*** the bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor, and at an inconvenient time ***so that*** the Contractor struggles to engage lawyers to prevent the bank from paying out on the Performance Bond.

Comment: "so that" means "in order that"

Answer (score 4):

> *Firstly, the Employer will make a demand on the bank which provided*
> *the PB. For tactical reasons, this demand is often made* [*so that the*
> *bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor*], *and at*
> *an inconvenient time* [*so that the Contractor struggles to engage*
> *lawyers to prevent the bank from paying out on the Performance Bond*].

Preliminary point: "so that" is not a syntactic unit, not a 'compound subordinator. The bracketed expressions are purpose adjuncts consisting of the preposition "so" followed by a declarative content clause as its complement.

Some older grammars claim that "so that" is a syntactic unit, a constituent, but this is wrong. It actually consists of the preposition "so" with a declarative content clause as its complement. We know this to be the case because the subordinator "that" is readily omissible.

Comment: May I ask what your major was/is?

Comment: That's correct as far as normative language goes. But since everybody makes up their own grammar, for some people _so that_ may well function as a constituent, even though for most it doesn't. The same is true of many constituent types, especially preposition phrases -- transitivizing prepositions like the _at_ in _look at_ are basically Schrödinger's preposition -- you can't tell whether they're attached to the verb or the object in most cases. Leaving it unlabelled bothers some linguists and not others.

Comment: The fact that _that_ is readily omissible is sufficient evidence to support the claim that "so that" consists of two constituents: prep head + content clause complement.

Answer (score -1):

In *The Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, "*so that*" is considered to be a subordinating conjunction, otherwise called a subordinator.

> **14.11** p. 998
> Subordinators
> SUBORDINATORS (or more fully SUBORDINATING CONJUNCTIONS) are the most
> important formal device of subordination, particularly for finite clauses. Like
> prepositions, which they resemble in having a relating function, subordinators
> forming the core of the class consist of a single word, but there is a larger
> range of complex subordinators which function, to varying degrees, like a
> single conjunction.
> […]

> **14.12** […]
> SIMPLE SUBORDINATORS
> *after, although, as, because, before, directly (informal, esp BrE), if,
> immediately (informal, esp BrE), lest (esp AmE), like (informal, esp
> AmE), once, since, that, though*
> […]
>
> COMPLEX SUBORDINATORS
> ending with *that*:
>         *but that, in that, in order that, insofar that (formal, rare), in the event that,
> save that (literary), such that*
> ending with optional *that*:
> (a) participle form:
>         [*assuming, considering, excepting, given, granted,granting, provided, providing, seeing, supposing* ] (*that*)
> (b) others:
>         [*except, for all, now, so*] (*that*)

> **14.13**
> CORRELATIVE SUBORDINATORS
> (a) as … so
> (b) as … as
>       so … as
>       such… as
>       so … (that)
>       such …(that)
> […]

> **15.20** p. 1070
>
> Adjuncts and disjuncts
> 15.20
> Adjuncts and disjuncts tend to differ semantically in that adjuncts denote
> circumstances of the situation in the matrix clause, whereas disjuncts
> comment on the style or form of what is said in the matrix clause (style
> disjuncts) or on its content (content or attitutlinal disjuncts). The primary
> difference is that they differ syntactically in that disjuncts are peripheral to
> the clause to which they are attached.
> The syntactic difference does not manifest itself in differences in form or
> position. For example, finite clauses that function as adjuncts and disjuncts
> may share the same subordinator, and in both functions the clauses may be
> positioned initially or finally. The peripheral status of disjuncts is indicated
> mainly negatively: they do not allow a number of syntactic processes to apply
> to them that are allowed by adjuncts, processes that reflect a measure of
> integration within the superordinate clause.
> In this section we consider the differences between adjunct and disjunct
> clauses. Below we exemplify the contrasts between adjunct clauses in the [a]
> sentences and content disjunct clauses in the [b] sentences:
> […]
> purpose *so that* [a] and result *so that* [b]:
> ♦ They took a plane so that they could get there early. [a]
> ♦ We know her well, so that we can speak to her on your behalf.[b]

> Clauses of result
> **15.49**
> Clauses of result are introduced by the subordinators *so that* (formal) and *so*.
> These clauses overlap with those of purpose both in meaning and in
> subordinators. The chief semantic difference is that result clauses are factual
> rather than putative: both express result, but in the result clause the result is
> achieved, whereas in the purpose clause it is yet to be achieved - it is a
> desired or aimed-at result. Hence finite clauses of result do not require a
> modal auxiliary:
> ♦ We paid him immediately, so (that) he left contented. [result]
> [1]
> ♦ We paid him immediately so (that) he would leave contented.
> [purpose] [2]

> Note[b] […] If so
> intensifies a verb it may appear at the end of the clause, and an intonation break (or in writing, a comma) is normal after so:
> ♦ They wanted it so, (that) they agreed to pay more than the normal price. [so = 'so much']
> In formal style, so may be a manner adverb rather than an intensifier, in which case that must be retained:
> ♦ They *so* arranged the seating *that all had a clear view of the stage*. [so = 'in such a way'] (formal)
> Again, so may be postposed:
> ♦ They arranged the seating *so, that all had a clear view of the stage*. (formal)

*Some minor changes are needed in the initial sentence*

- Firstly, the Employer will make a demand on the bank which provided the PB. For tactical reasons, this demand is often made so, that the bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor, and at an inconvenient time, so that the Contractor struggles to engage lawyers to prevent the bank from paying out on the Performance Bond.
- (equivalent) *Firstly, the Employer will make a demand on the bank which provided the PB. For tactical reasons, this demand is often **so** made, that the bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor, and at an inconvenient time, so that the Contractor struggles to engage lawyers to prevent the bank from paying out on the Performance Bond.*

The first occurrence of "so that" is that of "so" as an adverb of manner and of the conjunction "that" which constitute a *correlative subordinator* introducing a result clause; "so" means "*in such a manner*". The second  is that of  the *complex subordinator*, and it introduces a result clause.

Comment: The Comprehensive is wrong about this. "So that" is not a complex subordinator (subordinate conjunction), but the prep "so" + declarative content clause as its complement. This is evident from the fact that the subordinator "that" is readily omissible.  Your changes to the OP's example are wrong -- the original was fine with "so" + content clause complement.

Comment: @BillJ  1/ "So" is in no way a preposition; it can be only _adv_, _conj._ or _noun_ (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/so_1#so_idmg_6); 2/ In this first occurrence, the combination "so that" is not explained in my answer as a complex subordinator, but instead as a _correlative subordinator_: this corresponds to the fact that the formulation in which "so" is not posposed (the second) is also correct and means the same thing. 3/ There is only one change, and that is the addition of a comma

Comment: It's not correlative, and nor is it _ever_ a complex subordinator, for the reason I gave. "So" + its complement should not be separated by a comma. You've got the syntax wrong. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/so).

Comment: @BillJ Your analysis introduces "so" as a preposition, but nowhere is there a dictionary or a grammar defining this word as a preposition.  Here is another dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so What do you do with the notions of purpose and result associated traditionally with "so that"? Do they remain in your theory? They imply two idiomatic renderings for "so that" as a complex subordinator; it is not an analysable unit (unless it is a correlative, and then there should be a comma).

Comment: I sent you a link to a dictionary that gives this "so" as a preposition. And the finest grammar available today, H&P's CGEL, also gives it as a prep. Of course it's analysable: prep + content clause, as I said earlier.

Comment: Also, it would seem perverse to claim that "so that" is a syntactic unit in view of the fact that the "that" component is readily omissible: "... this demand is often made so (that) the bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor".

Comment: @BillJ re your link — That does not fit the characteristics of a preposition, they are wrong and they are the only one claiming that; first example they give: "The person locks the door so no one is able to come in and take things." . "no one is able to come in and take things" is not a prepositional complement: it is not a noun phrase, not a nominal wh-clause, not a nominal -ing clause; those are the only elements that can be prepositional complements, they have to be noun-like in nature. Instead of that you have  a subordinate idea expressed by the verb and that calls for a subordinator.

Comment: @BillJ Your interpretation of the sentence is not a possibility, simply because of the adjunct "For tactical reasons"; it is a claim that banks are perpetually overworked because of the great frequency of the demand; that is not so. A  realistic interpretation is "Often, tactical reasons result in the  demand being made in such a manner that…". Anything else makes no sense.

Comment: No: it's simply a purpose adjunct in clause structure. In ".. so (that) the bank has as little time as possible to inform the Contractor", "that" is an optional subordinator. Simple basic grammar!

Comment: @BillJ You do not answer even a quarter of my questions. Since when can a prepositional complement be any clause? What word does "often" modify? This is grammar without theory to back it up, merely I-say-so grammar. Why don't you provide references for your claims?

Comment: Your questions are not relevant since they are based on false premises. I've already given you an authoritive ref: H&P's CGEL, which is far better than Quirk et al's Comprehensive.

Comment: @BillJ CGEL is no authority for me; would I be in need of a new grammar I'd choose right away the latest edition of CoGEL.

Comment: Which would explain why you don't understand Present-day English grammar. CGEL is clearly too advanced for you.

Comment: @BillJ Well, it is possible that somewhere my understanding will fail and it does sometimes, but the problem is that there are too many things in that grammar that go against the grain, too many things about which I can't change my understanding, as I find it the only one possible (for now at least).